# incompatible with other application(s) using the same shared user id

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, system-error

I have a [nexus-5](/questions/tagged/nexus-5) with Android Kitkat 4.4.4, no [root](/questions/tagged/root) or anything like that.
I tried to install the game "The Walking Dead: Season Two" but after the download I got this error: incompatible with other application(s) using the same shared user ID. I don't know how to fix it.

Note: It's important for me to say that I don't understand about  ROM, ROOT and how the Android OS works. So please; if you post an answer, write as many details as you can.
I very much appreciate the help!

Thank you.

The error Message:

[image]

Comment: Have you [side-loaded](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/side-loading/info) any apps (i.e. installed from different sources)?

Comment: Do you have any other apps by the same developer?

Comment: yes,i have the walking dead: season one on my device but i don't think that suppose to do any problems.... i installed it from a different source (not play store).